# Bad text look on Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I draw text throw TextPaint on Canvas. And in some cases it looks terible:

240*320 API 7
[image: 240*320 API 7]

240*320 API 7
[image: 240*320 API 7]

240*320 API 15
[image: 240*320 API 15]

In some cases good:

720*1280 API 15
[image: 720*1280 API 15]

I use:
`TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();`

```
paint.setTextSize(height/20);
```

`canvas.drawText("Just text", x, y, paint);`

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

set the `antialiasing` flag to your `Paint` object. The flag is `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG`

```
TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

Comment: It uses anti-aliasing to basically smooth out the letters on your canvas. You can read more about aliasing here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing